# Setting up CORS in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cors

I'm in the process of creating my first ionic app, but I'm struggling with cors, I don't have a lot of experience on this  area, so this question may seem stupid.

I do not have access to the api site, so I can't change anything there.
This is the code I am using to get the data from the api site. I've read that the cors is only a problem when testing with ionic serve, but I've tried building the android app and transferring the apk to my phone, but it doens't seem to work there either (and I can't see the console log on my phone offcourse to test it :) )

```
  app.controller('VolleyCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
      $scope.wedstrijden = [];
      $http.get('http://www.volleyadmin2.be/services/wedstrijden_xml.php?province_id=5&stamnummer=O-0696&format=json')
        .success(function(response) {
          angular.forEach(response, function(child) {
            $scope.wedstrijden.push(child);
          })
        });

  });
```

Comment: If you use chrome, you can disable it checking for cors by opening it with --disable-web-security flag. Not sure what ionic serve does but I'd think you should be able to point chrome at the file system and have it work unless you're trying to do something requiring a device's stuff (which just calling a web service shouldn't be)

Comment: Yeah, I already tried with a chrome extension to disable the cors, and that works on my pc, but the problem is that it doens't work on my phone, I don't get the content, and I would think it is because off the cors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you're using a newer version of Cordova (or the latest Ionic CLI) to develop your app, you may be experiencing http 404 errors when your app tries to make network requests.

This can be solved quickly with [Cordova Whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

You can find more documentation on [Ionic docs: Cordova Whitelist](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist).

**Solution:**

Run the following command in your shell/terminal:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

The only thing you need to do now is to add a property to your `config.xml`
 file:

`<allow-navigation href="*" />`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, but I read in the output 'Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios', and I'm testing it on an android phone, is that a problem?

EDIT: it works on my android phone, but it didn't work in the ionic serve, sorry and thanks :)

Comment: Hm ok, let's try something else. Could you hook up your device onto your computer & debug it with Google Chrome? http://docs.ionic.io/docs/chrome-inspector

Now we can easily find out what's going wrong. Maybe its something else?

EDIT: Glad it works! You're welcome. :-)

Comment: Still good that you've added that link, will probably be needing that in the future a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of solutions without luck, finally

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

solved issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reason.

Handling CORS mean configuring backend and frontend.
In your backend, depends on which web server your api is running.

I don't think you're going to solve using the "...you can disable it checking for cors by opening it with --disable-web-security flag..."

It will be a good practice to handle only an http promise in controller and move the http request on a service.
I can tell you what I fixed to avoid the CORS preflight trouble.

By default, Angular set headers in $http.defaults.headers.{HTTP_VERB}.

My case was   $http.defaults.headers.post with a 'Content-type' : 'application/json'.
This kind of content type was triggering the cors in chrome.
Doesn't matter if you set 'Content-Type' manually. This is set by default in Angular.

So the fix is go to your app.js file and inside the .config section insert your code that will be a kinda of

`app.config(['$http', function ($http) {
    //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight) 
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
}]);`